# Prove that the following piecewise function is Borel measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

This question is a follow-up to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3872684/borel-measurable-function-that-shows-riemann-integral-is-insufficient) question. I am trying to prove that

$f(x) =
    \begin{cases}
    \dfrac{1}{b}\; \text{      if $x$ is rational and $x= \dfrac{a}{b}$ is in its lowest terms}\\
    34 \; \text{      $x$ is irrational}
    \end{cases}$

is Borel measurable. I had 2 ideas- the first was to show that this function is a composition of two Borel-measurable functions and the other was to express this function as a sum/product of two Borel-measurable functions. I couldn't develop either of these ideas fully. How can I prove that this function is Borel-measurable?

Comment: As an aside, this is (more or less) [Thomae's Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function). As people have said, this is measurable because you're modifying a measurable function (the constant $34$ function) on a set of measure $0$ (the rationals)

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I don't understand. They are modifying Thomae's function on irrationals -**not** a set of measure $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g=f|_{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $h=f|_{\mathbb{Q}^{c}}$, $h$ is a constant function and hence continuous with respect to subspace topology $\mathbb{Q}^{c}$, and we see that for any open set $\mathcal{O}$,
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}(\mathcal{O})&=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}:f(x)\in\mathcal{O}\}\cup\{x\in\mathbb{Q}^{c}:f(x)\in\mathcal{O}\}\\
&=g^{-1}(\mathcal{O})\cup h^{-1}(\mathcal{O}).
\end{align*}
$h^{-1}(\mathcal{O})$ is open with respect to $\mathbb{Q}^{c}$, and hence a Borel set.

We just need to justify that $g$ is Borel. But this is almost obvious since $g^{-1}(\{1/b\})$ is a discrete set for each $b\in\mathbb{Z}$. In fact,
\begin{align*}
g^{-1}(\mathcal{O})=\bigcup_{b\in\mathbb{Z},1/b\in\mathcal{O}}g^{-1}(\{1/b\}).
\end{align*}

Comment: Out of curiosity, since $h$ is non-strictly increasing on its domain, isn't it obvious that $h$ is Borel measurable?

Comment: Yes, you can argue with that.

Comment: In showing that $g$ is Borel measurable, you're using the fact that $\bigcup_{b\in\mathbb{Z},1/b\in\mathcal{O}}g^{-1}(\{1/b\})$ is a countable subset of $(0, \infty)$, correct?

Comment: Yes, this is one way of looking it. So countable set is definitely Borel as the countably union of singleton (closed set).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: If you modify a Borel function on a countable set, you get a Borel function.